# How do I divide data from a column in one table by data from a column in another table?

Tags: mysql

I'm pretty new to MySQL and am working on a query which should divide the data from a column in one table by the data from a column in another table. I've had a good hunt around the site but can't find quite what I'm looking for (or it may be a lack of understanding on my part). I wish to divide the  TotalSpend by TotalHires and think I'm pretty close but it's not quite right.

I have 4 rows of data in each column and am looking for 4 calculations to be executed. At the moment 16 results are being returned. I only wish to divide data which relates to the same member id but think that each cell in one column is being divided by each cell in the other column.
How can I alter my code to return only the desired 4 calculations?

Total spend:

```
SELECT garment_hire_header.member_id, garment_hire_line.hire_id, SUM(garment_hire_line.days*catalogue.daily_rate) AS 'Total Spend'
FROM garment_hire_line
JOIN garment_hire_header ON garment_hire_line.hire_id = garment_hire_header.hire_id
JOIN garment ON garment_hire_line.garment_id = garment.garment_id
JOIN catalogue ON garment.catalogue_id = catalogue.catalogue_id
Group by garment_hire_header.member_id
```

TotalHires:

```
SELECT garment_hire_header.member_id, COUNT(garment_hire_header.hire_id) as TotalHires
FROM garment_hire_header
Group by garment_hire_header.member_id
```

Nearly working final code (returns 16 calculations):

```
SELECT s.TotalSpend / h.TotalHires
from (SELECT SUM(garment_hire_line.days*catalogue.daily_rate) AS TotalSpend
FROM garment_hire_line
JOIN garment_hire_header ON garment_hire_line.hire_id = garment_hire_header.hire_id
JOIN garment ON garment_hire_line.garment_id = garment.garment_id
JOIN catalogue ON garment.catalogue_id = catalogue.catalogue_id
Group by garment_hire_header.member_id) s CROSS JOIN
(SELECT COUNT(garment_hire_header.hire_id) as TotalHires
FROM garment_hire_header
Group by garment_hire_header.member_id) h
```

---

Now that that's working I'm trying to push it a little bit further. I only want to display data if the hire_id is found in another query

I've tried adding the following which has worked in the past on different queries but for some reason is not working in this case:

```
WHERE garment_hire_line.hire_id IN
(SELECT hire_id, DATE_ADD(date_out, INTERVAL (days) DAY) AS 'Expected Return', DATEDIFF(return_date, DATE_ADD(date_out, INTERVAL (days) DAY)) as 'Days Late'
FROM garment_hire_line
WHERE DATEDIFF(return_date, DATE_ADD(date_out, INTERVAL (days) DAY)) > 0
ORDER BY hire_id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to fix this by just changing your `cross join` to a `left join` and then adding in the `member_id` to match up the tables. However, there is a much nicer approach to this situation:

```
SELECT garment_hire_header.member_id, garment_hire_line.hire_id, 
SUM(garment_hire_line.days*catalogue.daily_rate) AS 'Total Spend', 
SQ1.TotalHires, 
SUM(garment_hire_line.days*catalogue.daily_rate)/SQ1.TotalHires AS `Total`
FROM garment_hire_line
LEFT JOIN garment_hire_header ON garment_hire_line.hire_id = 
garment_hire_header.hire_id
LEFT JOIN garment ON garment_hire_line.garment_id = garment.garment_id
LEFT JOIN catalogue ON garment.catalogue_id = catalogue.catalogue_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT garment_hire_header.member_id, 
COUNT(garment_hire_header.hire_id) as TotalHires
FROM garment_hire_header
Group by garment_hire_header.member_id) AS SQ1 ON SQ1.member_id = 
garment_hire_header.member_id
Group by garment_hire_header.member_id;
```

I've left your initial code as it was as much as possible. The key point being that as you are using the same tables for the calculation you don't need to place everything into sub-queries. I also renamed your `joins` to `left joins`, this doesn't change the way the query works but it is nicer to specify the type of join you are doing.

Comment: Hi Martyn. Thanks very much, that returns what I was after. I think I've been over complicating things when trying different things out. Your reply has made me take a step back and re-evaluate. I might approach things slightly differently in the future. Cheers!